# Switch between a text field and label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am relatively new to rails. I have the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ8Vm.jpg).

I want a text field to replace the numbers when the update button is clicked as well as maintain the number previously there, with the button shown to change to a confirmation.

I have the following in my applicaton.

```
%tr[fund_flow]
  %td= fund_flow.symbol
  %td= fund_flow.trade_date
  %td= number_to_currency(fund_flow.nav, unit: '')
  %td= number_to_currency(fund_flow.shares_outstanding, unit: '')
  %td= label_tag("N/A", number_to_currency(fund_flow.fund_flow, unit: ''), {style: "#{'display:show' if flag}"})
  %td
    = form_tag(update_nav_history_path(fund_flow.id), method: "post") do
      = text_field_tag("update", nil, {style: "#{'display:none' if !flag}"})
      = submit_tag("Update")
```

The following helped me get this far. [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182346/rails-best-way-to-conditionally-show-hide-a-form-field)

Not sure how to set a global flag variable and change what happens when the flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

There are ruby gems that handle this exactly as you want. In particular I am using best_in_place. This allows to create fields that display as labels but turn into input fields if you click on them, or if you click on a button.

The input field can include buttons to confirm or cancel the change (or just respond to esc or enter keys, or click outside the field). After changing the value it calls the method to update the object and triggers a callback where you can display a confirmation message. You can also perform validations and display error messages.

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

**Some images:**

[image]

[image]

It also handles select boxes:

[image]

[image]